# Repository pattern and TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

Consider Order(aggregate root) entity having a collection of OrderItem.

```
class Order
{
  public string Number;
  public List<OrderItem> OrderItems;
}
class OrderItem
{
  public string Name;
  public float Price;
}
```

then OrderRepository like this:

```
class OrderRepository
{
  IDbConnection connection;
  void SaveOrder(Order o)
  {
    connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Order ...");
    
    foreach(var oi in o.OrderItems)
    {
      connection.Execute("INSERT INTO OrderItem ...");
    }
  }
}
```

The question is whether TransactionScope should be placed in OrderRepository. Something like this:

```
class OrderRepository
{
  IDbConnection connection;
  void SaveOrder(Order o)
  {
    using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
      connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Order ...");
    
      foreach(var oi in o.OrderItems)
      {
        connection.Execute("INSERT INTO OrderItem ...");
      }
      scope.Complete();
    }
  }
}
```

My considerations on this:
We need to ensure that data is consistent after calling Save. This means that without any TransactionScope, inside repository or outside, this may result in some OrderItems committed and some not (exception). Then we can have:

1. TransactionScope only outside repository. Wrapping multiple repository calls.

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  orderRepository.Save(order);
  warehouseRepository.Save(...);
}
```

2. TransactionScope both outside 1) and inside repository (see above).

The issue I see with 1) is that OrderRepository needs to make an assumption that the calling code will provide TransactionScope. Otherwise it can't guarantee a consistent persistence for Order aggregate.

Comment: UoW doesn't mean using database transactions, keeping a transaction open for a long time and blocking other connections. That guarantees bad performance and deadlocks. Advanced ORMs like EF Core and NHibernate cache all changes and only open a connection to persist them in a single transaction when you call `SaveChanges`. They're far higher level constructs than single-entity repositories

Comment: If I'd call your `SaveOrder` method, I'd expect it to take care of the full transaction handling - including the commit and rollback if something went wrong. Especially with the repository pattern, where you should not know whether an HTTP API call or a DB operation is executed.

Comment: If your 'Order' is an aggregate root then changes to that should be, according to DDD recommendations, the boundary of a transaction. The fact that your use case is modifying two aggregate roots in a single transaction suggests that you've not modelled the aggregate roots in the most appropriate way.

Comment: @DavidOsborne, what would be the most appropriate approach in this case? Does having boundary at aggregate level mean that we can't also have outer transaction?  Say we are placing and order and we would like to create order in Order domain and also reserve items in the Warehouse domain. And we want to do this in a single transaction. Please note that this is just an example made up to discuss the concept. Taking pure DDD and transactions, skipping ORMs, microservices, SAGAs, performance, locking, etc.

Comment: The approach depends on your domain, so there's no easy way to outline what must be done. This series (https://www.dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_1.pdf) explains aggregate design well. My main point was that, if you model the aggregates correctly, you could put the transaction outside or inside the repository as the net effect would be the same as there is only one repository involved. Your example has two repositories, which suggests two aggregate roots, and that appears at odds with the DDD principles.

Comment: @DavidOsborne, thanks for the link. On page 3 we have an example with a service method planProductBacklogItem. This method is marked as Transactional and is making calls to productRepository and backlogItemRepository. In other place it states that "aggregate is synonymous with transactional consistency boundary". So the question is whether method backlogItemRepository.add(plannedBacklogItem) should also be marked Transactional inside backlogItemRepository? If it is not, it would have to rely it's transactional consistency on the caller.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok for a repository to assume itself operating under the context of a transaction initiated in a higher level (i.e. a use-case). Moreover, it should not care at all for the context under which it may or may not operate.

So, initiating a transaction inside a repository is not recommended.

You may want to have multiple repository objects for multiple entities composing a single aggregate, meaning they all have to operate under a single transaction. A transaction is essentially a unit-of-work, and a unit-of-work is an abstraction that should present in the application layer.

Comment: TransactionScope allows nesting. Inner TransactionScope will (by default) use SqlTransaction started in an Outer TransactionScope (if present). So from repository perspective it ensures that all operations it performs will be transactional. It does not need to assume that the caller started SqlTransaction. At the same time it will join SqlTransaction from the 'context' given by the caller (if caller is using TransactionScope). I can understand the drawbacks you pointed out for using SqlTransaction but I don't really see them for TransactionScope.